# Initializing static const in a class that extends a template

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, rtti

Consider this pseudocode:

```
class Foo {
public:
    virtual int getID() const = 0;
}

template<typename T>
class Blah : public Foo {
public:
    T data;
    static const int ID;  //static ID
    int getID() const { return Blah<T>::ID; }  //instance returns the ID
}

class Dude : public Blah<int> {
}
int Dude::ID = 10;  //I want to define Blah<int>::ID here, but how?

int receive(const Foo& foo) {
    if(foo.getID() == Dude::ID) {
        cout << "Received a Dude" << endl;
    }
}
```

This piece of code fails to compile because ISO C++ does not permit the ID in the `Blah` template to be defined as the ID in the `Dude` class.  I understand why because I could have multiple classes that extend a `Blah<int>`.

I understand if I put `template<typename T> int Blah<T>::ID = 10' in the Blah<T>` impl that it will work...but that isn't what I want...I want the derived class to define the ID...

Do I have to push the ID and getID() into the derived class?  I guess ultimately I'm interested in some RTTI so I can process the `Foo` appropriately.  If anyone has a better pattern, I'm all ears.

**EDIT**
In response to some of the comments...I would like to uniquely identify classes that derive from `Foo` via some ID so I can compare the runtime id of some `Foo` object to a specific class id.

Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure I understand the problem correctly. Have you checked CRTP? It might be useful here. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern

Comment: @Asha: I'm not familiar with CRTP...but I don't believe I want to derive Dude using itself as a template param.

Comment: You're asking about [a step and not a goal](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html), that makes [it impossible to answer](http://jalf.dk/blog/2010/09/yes-youre-going-to-have-to-tell-me-what-your-question-is-before-i-can-answer-it/). What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @GMan: Handy link...thanks...and I updated my question.

Comment: @TReddy: Possibly I may misunderstand the question, but doesn't `typeid`
or `dynamic_cast` meet the purpose?

Comment: @Ise: Given that any type of `Foo` can be passed to `receive`, In some cases a switch is better than if/else block especially for classes that have a large `receive` implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this answer that does exactly what I'm after...sorry if my question was confusing.

[in C++, how to use a singleton to ensure that each class has a unique integral ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2172879/in-c-how-to-use-a-singleton-to-ensure-that-each-class-has-a-unique-integral-id)

Answer (score 1):

Make the static int ID; private, and provide GetID in public interface, make SetID a protected interface. But that is not a good solution, because all the derived class will share the same ID, which is not what you want.

A better way should be you use the id as the base class' template parameter, then class Derived : public Base<234>{} will work.

Or add virtual const int GetID() = 0 into Base class.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simply do this:

```
class Dude : public Blah<int> {
}
 static const int Dude_ID; //declaration!

int receive(const Foo& foo) {
    if(foo.getID() == Dude::Dude_ID) {
        cout << "Received a Dude" << endl;
    }
}
static const int Dude::Dude_ID = 10; // definition!
```

Similarly, define an ID for each derived class.

---

Yet another way to have an ID for each class is this:

```
template<typename T, int ID=1>
class Blah : public Foo {
public:
    int getID() const { return ID; }  
}

template<int ID=10>
class Dude : public Blah<int> {
public:
    int getID() const { return ID; }  
}
```

Comment: I mention your answer in my question...I'm just wondering if I can avoid all of that boilerplate coding because I have dozens of classes that extend Blah...

Comment: I see...a couple questions...do you mean to make Dude a template class ...would you not just say class Dude : public Blah<T, 10>?

Comment: @T Reddy: Yes Dude a class template now. And since ID has default value, that means it's optional for you to pass an argument for it. `Blah<int>` is enough!

Comment: @T Reddy: Of course. But you the syntax is slightly different, if you don't want to pass argument (as Dude's template parameter has default value), then do this : `new Dude<>()`. Else do this : new Dude<10>()`.

Comment: I don't think that's going to work for me because new Dude<>() isn't the same as new Dude<1>() for instance...a Dude is just a Dude IMHO...  ;)

Comment: @T Reddy: Then why do you need ID then. All Dudes are not same!

Comment: because the ID belongs to an Foo...and it uniquely identifies a class of Foo...in this case `Dude`